# Why do i get this error message while trying to run sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, upgrade, python

I want to upgrade my python version 2.7 on ubuntu 14.04 to 3.7
If i run sudo apt-get update, a lot of error message will be displayed.
 i had tried a lot of of suggestions but none work.
Can someone help me out please.

Here are the errors i got:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Comment: You get this error because Ubuntu 14.04 is already end of life and the repository is essentially dead. Please upgrade to a supported Ubuntu version. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: You need to [upgrade to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/167115).

Answer (score 0):

> Ubuntu 14.04 is already end of life ...

Please also note that both Python2 and 3 are installed on at least 16.04 and onward;

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12

$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Also notable is that important parts of Ubuntu support software depends on at least Python 2.x - therefore, for a beginner, an upgrade of python2 is likely to be a **horrendous** task.

**Some software are better left to be upgraded at/in/with OS upgrades only.**

Comment: Thanks man i appreciate

Comment: e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211848/installing-python3-7-after-uninstalling-python3-6