# Installing python3.7 after uninstalling python3.6

Tags: python

How can I install python3.7 after uninstalling python3.6, which is pre-installed **through terimal**?

Answer (score 3):

You don't - you should not be touching the preinstalled Python 3.6 without knowing what you're doing because **this will heavily damage your system and make it break hard**.

By *uninstalling* Python 3.6, you've just broken pretty much every package management script that runs behind the scenes.  And not every script is updated to work with Python 3.7 (this is why Python 3.6 is still the version in that Ubuntu install that comes preinstalled).

The only way to 'repair' this is to install Python 3.6 again, then install Python 3.7 separately with something like [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to create an isolated Python 3.7 on your home directory that would be usable by you for your various projects.

Removing the system preinstalled python just to upgrade it to 3.7 is a **lesson in futility** because you're breaking your system in the process, and anything else that you try and install that has a Python 3 dependency in their package dependency declarations is going to go and reinstall Python 3.6 again and you're back in the same boat again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.